# vsftpd custom anonymous root folder

Tags: fedora, selinux, vsftpd

The default folder shared for the anonymous user by vsftpd is /var/ftp. This works fine. Now I want to share a different folder. I added this line to /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf:

```
anon_root=/data/downloads/
```

But it doesn't work. Clients that could connect before now simply fail to connect. What am I missing?

The logs don't show anything but some client having connected. I'm running on Fedora Server; thus, yes, SELinux. Actually, /data is the mountpoint for another partition.

Ok, so SELinux is to blame. In permissive mode there is no problem.

```
$ sudo ausearch -ts recent -m avc
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:22:59 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664979.645:273): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1163 comm="vsftpd" name="/" dev="dm-1" ino=128 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:23:01 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664981.026:274): avc:  denied  { search } for  pid=1162 comm="vsftpd" name="downloads" dev="dm-1" ino=131 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:23:01 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664981.179:275): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1162 comm="vsftpd" name="downloads" dev="dm-1" ino=131 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:23:01 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664981.179:276): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=1162 comm="vsftpd" path="/" dev="dm-1" ino=131 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:23:01 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664981.179:277): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1162 comm="vsftpd" path="/" dev="dm-1" ino=131 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
----
time->Wed Dec 21 17:23:01 2022
type=AVC msg=audit(1671664981.448:278): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1167 comm="vsftpd" path=2F54726F6C6C20283230323229205B31303830705D205B5745425269705D205B352E315D205B5954532E4D585D2F7777772E5954532E4D582E6A7067 dev="dm-1" ino=134 scontext=system_u:system_r:ftpd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

Comment: Amything useful in the logs? Which OS? Apparmor/SELinux?

Comment: @Edward: I've edited my question.

Comment: Please test with SELinux in permissive mode (run `sudo setenforce 0`). If that works, SELinux is the culprit. Then post output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc`.

Comment: @Edward: It seems your hunch is correct. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux is blocking access to your filesystem. This is the correct behaviour when you share paths that aren't shared by default.

Give your directory the correct SELinux context:

```bash
# sudo semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t /data/downloads/
# sudo restorecon -Rv /data/downloads/
```

To allow VSFTPD access to all files on your system (limited by VSFTPD config and correct FS access permissions of course), set the appropriate SELinux boolean by running:

```bash
# sudo setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

Comment: Instead of giving full access, how can I narrow access permission to /data/downloads?

Comment: I assume there must be a rule that grants vsftpd access to /var/ftp, because that did work out of the box. Maybe I can copy that rule?

Comment: Yes. that's also possible. I edited my answer.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I've used `public_content_t` instead of `public_content_rw_t`. I assume _rw_ grants write access; I just need read access. `ls -Z /data/` shows the type `default_t`. Should'nt it be `public_content_t`now?

Comment: If you want everything under `/data/` to be accessible, you should put `/data/` in the `semanage` and `restorecon` commands instead of `/data/downloads/`.

Comment: No, just /data/downloads. `ls -Z /data` shows the type of the downloads folder to be `default_t`. I expected it to be `public_content_t`. Sorry, that wasn't very clear in my previous comment.